# Custom function to apply bold face to a region

Tags: faces, region

I know there is a function called: `facemenu-set-bold`, which is bound to **M-o b**, but I'm trying to write my own as an exercise. Here is my code:

```
(defun my-function()
  "this is my function"
  (interactive)
  (facemenu-set-face 'bold))
```

When I select a region and call this function using `M-x my-function`, the region itself is not affected, only the newly inserted text is bold, can someone please, explain to me why.

Comment: Do you want to do it with text-properties; or, would you prefer to do it with overlays?

Comment: The easiest one, I'm not sure of what 'overlays' mean.

Comment: See function `put-text-property` (for property `face`) - `C-h f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`facemenu-set-face`  checks the active region within its [`interactive` form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html). If you call it as a function that form is not evaluated.

If you would call it through `call-interactively` then the interactive form of `facemenu-set-face` also asks for the face. That is also something you probably do not want.

If you insist on using `facemenu-set-face` the way out is to provide the arguments `START` and `END` yourself.
You can copy the relevant lines from the interactive-form of `facemenu-set-face`.
If you have installed the elisp sources you find the definition of `facemenu-set-face` by:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `facemenu-set-face` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

```el
(defun my-function()
  "this is my function"
  (interactive)
  (facemenu-set-face 'bold
             (if (and mark-active (not current-prefix-arg))
             (region-beginning))
             (if (and mark-active (not current-prefix-arg))
             (region-end))
             ))
```

Comment: When I type `M-x find-function RET facemenu-set-function RET` I get *[no match]*, and when I use `M-.` I get *No definitions found for: facemenu-set-function*, how can I fix this please?

Comment: @BiteBytes That was a typo. I've corrected the answer.